# General formulation of the product arbitrary moment generating functions X and Y

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Given that X and Y are independent random variables, with moment generating functions M and N, respectively, is there a generic formula to produce the moment generating function of X*Y?

Comment: I love questions without any effort from the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the law of total expectation. For instance, if $Y$ is a discrete r.v 
\begin{align}
M_{XY}(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tXY}] &= \sum_{y} \mathbb{E}[e^{tXY}|Y=y]\mathbb{P}[Y=y] \\ 
&=\sum_{y} \mathbb{E}[e^{tXy}]\mathbb{P}[Y=y] \\
&=\sum_{y} M_{X}(ty) \mathbb{P}[Y=y],
\end{align}
where the second equality follows from the independency of $X$ and $Y$. Similarly, for a continuous r.v $Y$ with density $f_Y$,
$$M_{XY}(t) = \int_{y} M_X(ty)f_Y(y)dy.$$